# Parsing quotes in string in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to parse the following string

```
val s1 = """ "foo","bar", "foo,bar" """
```

And out put of this parsing I am hoping is...

```
 List[String] ["foo","bar","foo,bar"] length 3
```

I am able to parse the following

```
val s2 = """ "foo","bar", 'foo,bar' """
```

By using the following pattern

```
val pattern = "(('[^']*')|([^,]+))".r

 pattern.findAllMatchIn(s2).map(_.toString).toList
 gives  ["foo","bar", 'foo,bar'] :length 3
```

EDIT
Currently I am able to parse:
   "foo,bar,foo bar" => [foo,bar,foo bar"]
    "foo,bar, 'foo bar' " => [foo, bar , 'foo bar'] //len 3

I want to parse these lines as well..

But I am not able to figure out the pattern for  s2.. Note that I need to parse both s1 and s2 successfully

Currently I am able to parse:

```
"foo,bar,foo bar" => [foo,bar,foo bar"]
    "foo,bar, 'foo bar' " => [foo, bar , 'foo bar'] //len 3
```

I want to parse these lines as well.. along with the following line:

```
 """ foo, bar, "foo,bar" """ // gives [foo,bar,"foo,bar"] len 3
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055727/negating-a-backreference-in-regular-expressions for some relevant patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for your `s1` and `s2` examples:

```
(["']).*?\1
```

`["']` matches a double or single quote (which is captured as a group). We then match anything followed by a closing quote that matches the opening quote (using the capture group `\1`). We use a non-greedy match `.*?` so that we don't consume the closing quote.

Note that you'll need to use triple quoting, since the pattern has a quote in it:

```
val pattern =  """(["']).*?\1""".r
```

**Update** to handle further cases added to question:

To also handle your comma-separated examples, you need to match combinations of word characters `\w` or whitespace `\s`, terminated by either a comma or the end of the line, but excluding the terminating character using a lookahead `(?=(,|$))`

```
(["']).*?\1|\w(\w|\s)*(?=(,|$))
```

Comment: Can you post the full regex patterns... I am not sure I understand??

Comment: @DNA.. sorry I guess I wasnt clear.. the current pattern can parse some other cases as well "foo,bar,foobar" or "foo,bar,'foo,bar'" .. Is there a way to modify your pattern.. to encompass these scenarios as well

Comment: Just to confirm the pattern is  val pattern = """(["']).*?\1|(\w|\s)+(?=(,|$))""".r

Comment: `val pattern = """(["']).*?\1|\w(\w|\s)*(?=(,|$))""".r` (I just edited it slightly)