# how to parse a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the following string

```
 s1 = """ "foo","bar", "foo,bar" """
```

And out put of this parsing I am hoping is...

```
 List ["foo","bar","foo,bar"] length 3
```

I am able to parse the following

```
s2 = """ "foo","bar", 'foo,bar' """
```

By using the following pattern

```
pattern = "(('[^']*')|([^,]+))"
re.findall(pattern,s2)
gives [('foo', '', 'foo'), ('bar', '', 'bar'), ("'foo,bar'", "'foo,bar'", '')]
```

But I am not able to figure out the pattern for  s2.. Note that I need to parse both s1 and s2 successfully

```
Edit
   The current pattern support strings like
   "foo,bar,foo bar" => [foo,bar,foo bar]
   "foo,bar,'foo bar'" => ["foo","bar",'foo bar']
    "foo,bar,'foo, bar'" => [foo,bar, 'foo, bar'] #length 3
```

Comment: @aliteralmind The beginning and end of the string literal

Comment: I use this:
http://regex101.com/#python

Comment: You posted almost the [same exact question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036791/parsing-quotes-in-string-in-scala), although for a different language (huh?) an hour ago.

Comment: @aliteralmind : Yepp.. I was trying in scala but gave it up and pivoted back to python :-/

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to do this using regex?

Comment: @DSM: Umm. I thought it was simpler.. basically I am trying to write a function which accepts string (quoted in question) and split it base on commas (based on the various conditions as quoted in question)..

Comment: @Fraz: this (a csv-like reader) is an example of something which is easy to describe statefully but annoying to squeeze into a regex.

Comment: If this is a csv, why don't you use python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead of trying to reinvent it with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
(?:"([^"]+)"|'([^']+)')
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mDgYt1X03ENIkzQG)

Capture groups 1 *or* two contain the desired output. So each element could be `$1$2`, because exactly one will always be empty.

---

Updated to the new requirements as in the comments to Haidro's answer:

```
(?:("[^"]+")|('[^']+')|(\w+))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/74oRfOiuxIFtrQxo)

Each element is now `$1$2$3`.

Answer (score 4):

I think that `shlex` ([simple lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html)) is much simpler solution here (when `regex` is too complicated). Specifically, I'd use:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> lex = shlex.shlex(""" "foo","bar", 'foo,bar' """, posix=True)
>>> lex.whitespace = ','        # Only comma will be a splitter
>>> lex.whitespace_split=True   # Split by any delimiter defined in whitespace
>>> list(lex)                   # It is actually an generator
['foo', 'bar', 'foo,bar']
```

Edit:

I have a feeling that you're trying to read a csv file. Did you try [`import csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Comment: Pretty cool solution. I think you mean that `lex` is a generator though, and that's why we need to call `list()`. A list is an iterator.

Comment: @Haidro - I always thought that iterator was an object that allows you to iterate, and generator is a function that allows you to iterate (using yield). I changed it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'["|\'](.*?)["|\']', s1)
['foo', 'bar', 'foo,bar']
>>> re.findall(r'["|\'](.*?)["|\']', s2)
['foo', 'bar', 'foo,bar']
```

This finds all the words inside of `"..."` or `'...'` and groups them.

Comment: @Hairdo Thanks for the pattern. it works.. but it fails at " foo,bar,'foobar' " Is it possible to support this as well?

Comment: So some strings are *not* quoted? It would be quite different to have to capture unquoted strings.

Comment: @Haidro : I updated the use case a bit ... can we support those cases as well?

Comment: Well now we need to know the *exact* format of those unquoted words. Are they truly words (only alpha-numeric)?

Comment: @aliteralmind: yepp.. they are alphanumeric.. everything I entered are valid python strings?

Comment: Can any of the elements be multiple words with spaces between?

Comment: Are you're saying that this is possible? `"foo bar baz,bar,'foo, bar'" => [foo bar baz,bar, 'foo, bar']`

Comment: @Fraz I don't know how to do the regular expression for it, but what you need to do is split by every comma except those inside of quotation marks

Comment: That's pretty important information, @Fraz! Sixth Sense question!  ;)