# How to negate backreference regex

Tags: regex, backreference

I'm making a regular expression to validate a password with the following requisites:

```
Have at least 6 characters.
Only have alphanumeric characters.
Don't have the same initial and ending character.
```

I thought about making it so that the first and last character match and then I would negate the backreference. My issue lies on how to negate that backreference. I looked for something stuff online but nothing worked. Here's what I got so far:

```
([\w])[\w]{3}[\w]+\1 //Generates a password with at least 6 chars in which the first and final characters match
```

Comment: According to this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055727/negating-a-backreference-in-regular-expressions - you'll want to use negative lookahead to negate the backreference. Just FYI, your regex will work for exactly 6 characters, but not at least six characters. Your `{3}` should be `{3,}` or even `{4,}` (you can remove that last `[\w]`. Also, you need not put `\w` inside square brackets, and it will allow non-alphanumerics (in this case, the underscore `_`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z])(?!.*\1$)[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM3dE9/1)

- `(?!.*\1$)` will make sure first and last characters are not same.
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,}` will make sure length is at least 6 and there are only alpha-numeric characters in input.

Comment: It does work, but I have no idea why this (?!.*\1$) makes the initial and final chars different.

Comment: It's a negative lookahead - it makes sure that the last character is not the same as the one captured in the first group.

Comment: `(?!.*\1$)` is a **negative lookahead** that means fail the match if last character is same as first character.

Comment: Ok so this is pretty much a template such as (?!.*<insert what you don't wanna finish with>$) ? I was trying to understand char by char so I could somehow pull it off myself

Answer (score 2):

use this pattern

```
^(?=[0-9-a-zA-Z]+$)(.).{4,}(?!\1).
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/162)