# Check in python if self designed pattern matches

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a pattern which looks like:

```
abc*_def(##)
```

and i want to look if this matches for some strings.
E.x. it matches for:

```
abc1_def23
abc10_def99
```

but does not match for:

```
abc9_def9
```

So the * stands for a number which can have one or more digits.
The # stands for a number with one digit
I want the value in the parenthesis as result

What would be the easiest and simplest solution for this problem?
Replace the * and # through regex expression and then look if they match?
Like this:

```
    pattern = pattern.replace('*', '[0-9]*')
    pattern = pattern.replace('#', '[0-9]')
    pattern = '^' + pattern + '$'
```

Or program it myself?

Comment: Regex is the best option in this case.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Why is hat your regular expression? Do you really want to match 0 or more copies of the letter c? Are you looking for something like `r'abc\d+_def\(\d\d\)'`?

Comment: i have many of the pattern which look like "abc*_def(##)". And was thinking that maybe there is an other solution than replacing the * and # through real regex expressions

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, I would go for a regex for the simple reason it's already available and tested, so it's easiest as you were asking.

The only "complicated" thing in your requirements is avoiding after `def` the same digit you have after `abc`.
This can be done with a [negative backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055727/negating-a-backreference-in-regular-expressions). The regex you can use is:

```
\babc(\d+)_def((?!\1)\d{1,2})\b
```

- `\b` captures word boundaries; if you enclose your regex between two \b
  you will restrict your search to words, i.e. text delimited by space,
  punctuations etc
- `abc` captures the string `abc`
- `\d+` captures one or more digits; if there is an upper limit to the number of digits you want, it has to be `\d{1,MAX}` where MAX is your maximum number of digits; anyway `\d` stands for a digit and `+` indicates 1 or more repetitions
- `(\d+)` is a group: the use of parenthesis defines `\d+` as something you want to "remember" inside your regex; it's somehow similar to defining a variable; in this case, `(\d+)` is your first group since you defined no other groups before it (i.e. to its left)
- `_def` captures the string `_def`
- `(?!\1)` is the part where you say "I don't want to repeat the first group after `_def`. `\1` represents the first group, while (?!whatever) is a check that results positive is what follows the current position is NOT (the negation is given by `!`) `whatever` you want to negate.

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PhsFpU/2).

Answer (score 0):

I had the hardest time getting this to work. The trick was the `$`

```
#!python2

import re

yourlist = ['abc1_def23', 'abc10_def99', 'abc9_def9', 'abc955_def9', 'abc_def9', 'abc9_def9288', 'abc49_def9234']

for item in yourlist:
    if re.search(r'abc[0-9]+_def[0-9][0-9]$', item):
        print item, 'is a match'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match your pattern like:

[`abc\d+_def(\d{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/quZQCM/1)

- `abc` Match literally
- `\d+` Match 1 or more digits
- `_` Match underscore
- `def` - Match literally
- `(` Capturing group (Your 2 digits will be in this group)

  - `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `)` Close capturing group

Then you could for example use [search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to check for a match and use `.group(1)` to get the digits between parenthesis.

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/TIZU34176)

You could also add word boundaries:

[`\babc\d+_def(\d{2})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/quZQCM/2)