# Use regex backreference inside character except class [^]

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets take:

`stringi = 'xnxx xnnx xnnxn'`

My regex is: `(n)[^n]`

I want to make my regex a little more dynamic like that:

`(n)[^\1]`  -`\1` beeing the capt. grp 1

My desired result would be that:

- `(n)[^\1]` would be equal `(n)[^n]`
- `(x)[^\1]` would be equal `(x)[^x]`

How can I not match a `NOT-\1` character?

Comment: Maybe `(n)(?!\1)`? You cannot use a backreference inside a character class.

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew result is not the same like `(n)[^n]`

Comment: `\1` inside a character class denotes an octal sequence. You need to use lookaheads to achieve expected result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055727/negating-a-backreference-in-regular-expressions

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew i'll have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a negative lookahead, the `.` is to match any character as `n` length is one

```
(n)(?!\1).
```

Comment: absolutely getting your idea. Very smart. Yet i don't get the same result as `(n)[^n]` on regex101.com.

Comment: I think I know why. The `.` does not consume new lines. Your solution is absolutely correct. Yet I know how I could tweak it. `(n)(?!\1)(?:.|[[:space:]])`

Comment: exactly `.` doesn't match newline by default but can be changed using flag `/s`, or depending engine `(?s).`