# Negating a backreference in regex

Tags: node.js, regex, backreference, regex-lookarounds, negation

I have written such regular expression:

```
(?<arg>(?<key>\w+)+=(?<quote>["'`])(?<value>(?:[^\k<quote>]|(?<=\\)\k<quote>)+\k<quote>))
```

but it doesn't work because of backreferencing inside [^]. I looked for solution on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055727/negating-a-backreference-in-regular-expressions) and wrote this:

```
(?<arg>(?<key>\w+)+=(?<quote>["'`])(?<value>(?:(?!\k<quote>).|(?<=\\)\k<quote>)+\k<quote>))
```

however it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

I want to extract all keys with values from strings like:

```
arg="value" arg='value' arg=`value` arg="value 'value'" arg='value \'value\' value' arg="value \"value\" value" arg=`value \`value\ value`
```

[regex101 - online preview](https://regex101.com/r/cUkNUz/2)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/cUkNUz/3

Comment: Thanks for your response, works like a charm, but it includes quote mark in value group. Isnt there a way to make it easier? Could as well repeat the code for all three quotes and it would be simular at length and probably more efficient.

Comment: There was no Value group, look, [I added it](https://regex101.com/r/cUkNUz/4).

Comment: Now it works like it should but still i think it can be optimized. 200ms for such a simple regex is a lot. Of course thanks for your time and i will use your regex if nothing else comes up.

Comment: It is not a simple regex, and it *is not* very efficient. However, regex101 shows 1 or 2 ms (JS regex option) with the current text input. If you need to faster code, why not write a normal parser? Or are you trying to replicate an HTML parser? Use an existing one.

Comment: Ah i see. Maybe because I’m browsing on mobile it shows 180ms. I think writing parser is more difficult. I’ll use it for chat messages containing commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may fix the regex by using the correct [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
(?<arg>               # Start arg group
  (?<key>\w+)         #  key group: 1+ word chars
  =                   # =
  (?<quote>['"`]?)    # quote group: an optional " ' or `
  (?<value>(?:(?!\k<quote>)[^\\])*(?:\\[\s\S](?:(?!\k<quote>)[^\\])*)*) # value group: any 0+ chars other than quote char with escaped quote chars allowed
  \k<quote>           # quote group value
)                     # end of arg group
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cUkNUz/5).

A one-liner:

```
(?<arg>(?<key>\w+)=(?<quote>['"`]?)(?<value>(?:(?!\k<quote>)[^\\])*(?:\\[\s\S](?:(?!\k<quote>)[^\\])*)*)\k<quote>)
```

See [demo.](https://regex101.com/r/cUkNUz/6)

Comment: Thanks! That’s weird. Previous link you sent me showed execution time at 180ms and this one shows 0ms.

Comment: @SebastianSzczepański The previous one contained a bug you had in your pattern, I replaced `(?<key>\w+)+` with `(?<key>\w+)`

Comment: Aaah I see. Haven’t noticed it. Thanks!