# How to use a numerical reference in neglected set?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a Regex expression with a numerical reference (to a capture group) in a neglected set.

Something like this:

```
 (["'])([^\1]*)(\1)
```

Basically it matches all strings with either a single or double quote surrounding it. For example:

`"foo bar" "foobar"` → `"foo bar"` and `"foo bar"`

---

The reason I can't just use the `(["'])([^"']*)(\1)` is the following scenario:

`"foo bar's" "foobar"`

Instead of matching `"foo bar's"` and `"foobar"` it matches `" "`.

---

How can I use numerical reference in a neglected set? If I can't how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: I have answered your question over at the duplicate marked one because that is not a duplicate of this and when a question is marked a duplicate, it is essentially unreachable (burried) for good.

Comment: @x15 If you feel this is not a duplicate situation you can vote to re-open this question? But you then should state in a comment how, *technically*, the information in the duplicate does not solve this problem. (I don't know enough about RegEx to be able to judge.)

Comment: @x15  thanks, the other question is similar enough and the answers apply to both that this can be considered a dup