# How to highlight SQL keywords using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, parsing, keyword

I would like to highlight SQL keywords that occur within a string in a syntax highlighter. Here are the rules I would like to have:

- Match the keywords SELECT and FROM (others will be added, but we'll start here). Must be all-caps
- Must be contained in a string -- either starting with `'` or `"`
- The first word in that string (ignoring whitespace preceding it) should be one of the keywords.

This of course is not comprehensive (can ignore escapes within a string), but I'd like to start here.

Here are a few examples:

- SELECT * FROM main -- will not match (not in a string)
- "**SELECT** name **FROM** main" -- will match
- "
        **SELECT** name **FROM** main" -- will match
- """Here is a SQL statement:

SELECT * FROM main""" -- no, string does not start with a keyword (SELECT...).

The only way I thought to do it in a single regex would be with a negative lookbehind...but then it would not be fixed width, as we don't know when the string starts. Something like:

- [`(?<=["']\s*(SELECT)\s*)(SELECT|FROM)`](https://regex101.com/r/AlfoxG/2)

But this of course won't work:

[image]

Would something like this be possible to do in a single regex?

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/RjrqlR/1)? Or [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%22%27%5d%5cs*%28SELECT%29%5cs*%5c*%5cs*%29%28%3f%3aSELECT%7cFROM%29&i=%22SELECT+*+FROM+table%22%0d%0a%22%0d%0a+++++SELECT+*+FROM+table%22%0d%0a%0d%0a%22%22%22%0d%0aUse+this+query+here%3a+%22SELECT+*+FROM+table%22%0d%0a%22%22%22%0d%0a%0d%0aSELECT+*+FROM+table&o=m)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yea, but only two should match, not all four (i.e., it's within a valid python string).

Comment: Not sure how you are going to do this without a proper parser. [This regex](https://regex101.com/r/gt5BqE/1) could help to some extent, but you would need to check groups that matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, yes that makes sense, thanks for the feedback on this.

Comment: `(?<=["']\s*(SELECT)\s*)(SELECT|FROM)` contains as variable width look behind, what regex engine is intended for ?

Answer (score 3):

A suitable regular expression is likely to get pretty complex, especially as the rules evolve further. As others have noted, it may be worth considering using a parser instead. That said, here is one possible regex attempting to cover the rules mentioned so far:

`(["'])\s*(SELECT)(?:\s+.*)?\s+(FROM)(?:\s+.*)?\1(?:[^\w]|$)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

### Online Demos

1. [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lgAIhJfsUBiJWTSD)
2. [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zPMHMm/5)

### Explanation

As can be seen in the above visualisation, the regex looks for either a double or single quote at the start (saved in capturing group #1) and then matches this reference at the end via `\1`. The `SELECT` and `FROM` keywords are captured in capturing groups #2 and #3. *(The `(?:x|y)` syntax ensures there aren't more groups for other choices as `?:` at the start of a choice excludes it as a capturing group.)* There are some further optional details such as limiting what is allowed between the `SELECT` and `FROM` and not counting the final quotation mark if it is immediately succeeded by a word character.

### Results

```
SELECT * FROM tbl        -- no match - not in a string
"SELECT * FROM tbl"      -- matches - in a double-quoted string
'SELECT * FROM tbl;'     -- matches - in a single-quoted string
'SELECT * FROM it's      -- no match - letter after end quote
"SELECT * FROM tbl'      -- no match - quotation marks don't match
'SELECT * FROM tbl"      -- no match - quotation marks don't match
"select * from tbl"      -- no match - keywords not upper case
'Select * From tbl'      -- no match - still not all upper case
"SELECT col1 FROM"       -- matches - even though no table name
'  SELECT  col1  FROM '  -- matches - as above with more whitespace
'SELECT col1, col2 FROM' -- matches - with multiple columns
```

### Possible Improvement?

It might also be necessary to exclude quotation marks from the "any character" parts. This can be done at the expense of increased complexity using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055727#8057827) by replacing both instances of `.*` with `(?:(?!\1).)*`:

`(["'])\s*(SELECT)(?:\s+(?:(?!\1).)*)?\s+(FROM)(?:\s+(?:(?!\1).)*)?\1(?:[^\w]|$)`

See [this Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6VebCv/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use capturing groups:

```
(.*["']\s*\K)(?(1)(SELECT|FROM).*(SELECT|FROM)|)
```

In this case $2 would refer to the first keyword and $3 would refer to the second keyword.  This also only works if there are only two keywords and only one string on a line, which seems to be true in all of your examples, but if those restrictions don't work for you, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the regexp bellow:

[image]

If you need to add other commands the thing may get a little trick, because some keywords doesn't apply. Eg: ALTER TABLE mytable or UPDATE  SET col = val;. For these scenarios you will need to create subgroups and the regexp may become slow.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements well I suggest that:

```
/^'\s*(SELECT)[^']*(FROM)[^']*'|^"\s*(SELECT)[^"]*(FROM)[^"]*"/m
```

[[Regex Fiddle Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/AlfoxG/4)

Explanation:

- When you need to check start of a string; use `^`.
- When you need to accept 0-n spaces; use `\s*`.
- When you need to accept new-line or multi-line strings; use `m` flag over your regex.
- When you need to use Case-Sensitive mode; Don't use `i` flag over your regex.
- When you need to block a string between a specific character like `"`; use `[^"]*` instead of `.*` that will protects first end of block.
- When you need to have a block with similar start and end characters like `'` & `"`; use `' '|" "` instead of `['"] ['"]`.

---

Update:
If you need to capture any *special keyword* after verifying existence of `SELECT` keyword after start of your string, I can update my solution to this:

```
/^'\s*(SELECT)([^']*(SELECT|FROM))+|^"\s*(SELECT)([^"]*(SELECT|FROM))+/m
```

Answer (score 0):

without parsing of quoted strings
could be done using `\G` and `\K` construct

`(?:"\s*(?=(?:SELECT|FROM))|(?<!^)\G)[^"]*?\K(SELECT|FROM)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/l8sgpM/1)