# Is it possible to use a capture group in the pattern given to a lookahead expression in a javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/(1+(?=0|$))|(0+(?=1|$))/
```

I use it on strings composed of only `0` and `1` characters to split the string in groups of `0`s and `1`s. Here my regex matches groups of `1`s followed by a `0` or an end of line `1+(?=0|$)` or groups of `0`s followed by a `1` or an end of line `0+(?=1|$)`.

```
> '001100011101'.split(/(1+(?=0|$))|(0+(?=1|$))/).filter(c=>!!c)
[ '00', '11', '000', '111', '0', '1' ]
```

I am wondering if I could get the same result using something like `/([01])+(?=[^$1]|$)/` to match `0`s or `1`s in a capture group (`([01])`) followed by not what was in the capture group `[^$1]`. This syntax clearly doesn't work and I can't find if something like this is possible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backreference needs to be outside of the character set (character sets don't accept backreferences like that).

In the pattern, you also need `\1`, not `$1`, and I don't think there's any need for the lookahead:

```js
console.log(
  '001100011101'.match(/([01])(?:\1)*/g)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your string consists only of 0 and 1, and you want to match sequences of 0 and 1, you don't need any groups.

You could either match 1 or more zeroes, or 1 or more one's using an alternation.

```
0+|1+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JSukgT/1)

```js
console.log('001100011101'.match(/0+|1+/g));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that doesn't answer my exact question but your logic is right and that's what I will end up using.

Answer (score 1):

There are three things to consider then:

- `.split()` will also output the captured substring
- You will thus need a `String.match()` and the regex will need a global flag
- You [can't use a backreference in the negated character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055727/negating-a-backreference-in-regular-expressions), you need to actually match a char and restrict it with a lookahead:

You can use

```js
console.log('001100011101'.match(/([01])+?(?=(?!\1).|$)/g))
// Further simplified to
console.log('001100011101'.match(/([01])\1*/g))
```

*Details*:

- `([01])+?` - one or more `0` or `1` chars, as few as possible, while capturing the digit into Group 1
- `(?=(?!\1).|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with any char but the one captured in Group 1 or end of string
- `([01])\1*` - a `0` or `1` captured into Group 1 and then 0 or more repetitions of the captured digit.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The note about `split` is useful too!

Comment: @statox I forgot to remove `.filter`, since with `match()`, you won't get any empty strings in the output.

Comment: Yes I did figured that out while testing, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @statox I hope you understand the non-capturing group is useless in `(?:\1)*`? Just use `/([01])\1*/g`, it is shorter and less cumbersome.